# How to add multiple select mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `$_REQUEST` but i dont know how to add multiple SELECT query with different function.

There it is :

```
if($_REQUEST['use_percents']!='true')
{
    $extra['SELECT'] = ",'' AS GRADE_PERCENT,'' AS REPORT_CARD_GRADE";
    $extra['functions'] = array('GRADE_PERCENT'=>'_makeGrade','REPORT_CARD_GRADE'=>'_makeGrade');

}
```

Here is the first function :

```
    function _makeGrade($value,$column)
{   global $THIS_RET,$current_RET,$import_RET,$grades_RET,$grades_select,$student_count,$tabindex;

    if($column=='REPORT_CARD_GRADE')
    {
        if(!isset($_REQUEST['_marking']))
        {
            $student_count++;
            $tabindex = $student_count;

            if($import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']])
            {
                $select = $import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['REPORT_CARD_GRADE_ID'];
                $extra_select = array($select=>$grades_select[$import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['REPORT_CARD_GRADE_ID']]);
                $div = false;
            }
            else
            {
                $select = $current_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['REPORT_CARD_GRADE_ID'];
                $extra_select = array();
                $div = true;
            }

            $return = SelectInput($select,'values['.$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID'].'][grade]','',$extra_select+$grades_select,false,'tabindex='.$tabindex,$div);
        }
        else
        {
            if($import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']])
                $select = $import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['REPORT_CARD_GRADE_ID'];
            else
                $select = $current_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['REPORT_CARD_GRADE_ID'];
            $return = '<b>'.$grades_RET[$select][1]['TITLE'].'</b>';
        }
    }
    elseif($column=='GRADE_PERCENT')
    {
        if($import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']])
            $select = $import_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['GRADE_PERCENT'];
        else
            $select = $current_RET[$THIS_RET['STUDENT_ID']][1]['GRADE_PERCENT'];
        $return = $select==''?'':($select+0).'%';
    }

    return $return;
}
```

i have other function, but confused to adding onto the `$_REQUEST`...
anyone can help me with this?...

For further files, you can view from google code : 
[Here](https://code.google.com/p/opensis-ao/source/browse/modules/Grades/InputFinalGrades.php)
Thanks :)